# re-enumerar los primary key con atributo auto incrementmysql

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos

tengo un a BD con 278 registros que los importe desde excel en formato CSV, el problema es que me empezo a numerar los id desde el 278 en adelante ahora lo que quiero es numerarlos correlativamente desde el 1... cabe mencionar que son primary key auto increment

Comment: Tal vez te pueda ayudar esta información: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/740358/reorder-reset-auto-increment-primary-key

Answer (score 2):

Realmente hay una triquiñuela muy simple que puedes implementar.

```
SELECT @razondecambio:=(MIN(id) - 1) FROM tabla; -- @razondecambio:=277
UPDATE tabla SET id=id-@razondecambio;           -- 1er registro: id=(278-271)=1
SELECT @maximo:=MAX(id) FROM tabla;           
ALTER TABLE tabla AUTO_INCREMENT = @maximo + 1;
```

Notaras que es realmente un juego:

1. consultas cual el menor valor de tu campo auto-incrementable.
2. actualizas cada valor teniendo en cuenta el obtenido anteriormente, puesto cualquier valor por encima de este corre el riesgo de estar duplicado y dado que como es una llave primaria, esto seria un problema.
3. consultas cual es el máximo valor actual de tu nueva numeración.
4. actualizas el contador de tu tabla con un incremento sobre el máximo actual.

Espero que te se muy útil.

Answer (score 1):

debes de actualizar el **`AUTO-INCREMENT`** de la tabla

```
ALTER TABLE tu_tabla AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;
```